# How can I make the explosion affect only the x-axis and not the y-axis in unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

this is the code
I add force but I want that the force Will be only on the x-axis and not on the y-axis

```
 Collider2D[] objects = Physics2D.OverlapCircleAll(transform.position, radius, Layertohit);

        foreach (Collider2D obj in objects)
        {
            Vector2 dir = obj.transform.position - transform.position;
            dir.y = 0;
            obj.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().AddForce(dir * force);
        }

        void OnDrawGizmosSelected()
        {
            Gizmos.color = Color.red;
            Gizmos.DrawWireSphere(transform.position, radius);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can freeze the y axis like

```
foreach (Collider2D obj in objects)
    {
        Vector2 dir = obj.transform.position - transform.position;
        dir.y = 0;
        float y=obj.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocit.y 
        obj.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().AddForce(dir * force);
        obj.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity=new Vector2(obj.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity.x,y)
    }
```